# Relentless Server DDoS attacks on all admin opencart

Tags: opencart, whm, ddos, mod-security

We have a rather difficult case of attacks on our VPS server

(CLOUDLINUX 7.9 kvm [web] v98.0.9)
Server Version: Apache/2.4.51 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.1.1l Apache mod_bwlimited/1.4

mainly in the form:

```
http/1.1    example-domain.com:443    POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1
```

that target the admin section of opencart installations in the server (~40 accounts).

Example:

| Srv | PID | Acc | M | CPU | SS | Req | Dur | Conn | Child | Slot | Client | Protocol | VHost | Request |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0-5 | 26445 | 0/358/943 | _ | 717.80 | 15 | 250 | 768524 | 0.0 | 9.62 | 20.16 | xx.xx.xx.xx | http/1.1 | exampledomain.comm:443 | POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1 |

we have csf v14.11, mod security with GotRoot rules, but attacks cannot be stopped.

we are also trying to block the attacks as per account editing the admin script to give

Code:
HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
for these attacks.

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: This thread might be of interest for you: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/block-abusive-requests-to-website.618263/